# Getting concrete values from a model containing "array-ext"

Tags: z3

When I combine arrays and quantifiers, Z3 often produces models containing applications of `array-ext`.  For example, [this test case](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/vLXJ) produces the following model:

```
(define-fun pipeid () (Array Int Int)
  (_ as-array k!2))
(define-fun valid () (Array Int Bool)
  (_ as-array k!0))
(define-fun ispipe () (Array Int Bool)
  (_ as-array k!1))
(define-fun pipeid_ab () Int
  2)
(define-fun fd () Int
  0)
(define-fun k!3 ((x!1 Int)) Int
  (ite (= x!1 0) 0
    (array-ext (_ as-array k!0) (_ as-array k!1))))
(define-fun k!0!4 ((x!1 Int)) Bool
  (ite (= x!1 3) false
    true))
(define-fun k!0 ((x!1 Int)) Bool
  (k!0!4 (k!3 x!1)))
(define-fun k!1 ((x!1 Int)) Bool
  true)
(define-fun k!2!5 ((x!1 Int)) Int
  (ite (= x!1 3) 4
    1))
(define-fun k!2 ((x!1 Int)) Int
  (k!2!5 (k!3 x!1)))
```

First, what does the `array-ext` in `k!3` mean?  I've pieced together that `(array-ext a b)` is some index *x* for which *a*[*x*] != *b*[*x*], but either what I've pieced together is incorrect or I can't wrap my head around the circular definitions of `k!0` and `k!3` above.

Second, how can I extract concrete values from such models?  I know that it's not in general possible to represent the concrete value of an array directly in the model, but I would like to at least understand what its concrete value is and be able to extract it in some form from the model.  Even querying for individual array indices doesn't seem to help:

```
 model.evaluate(pipeid[1]) => If(array-ext(as-array, as-array) = 3, 4, 1)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array-ext` is an internal function symbol. It is used to implement array extensionality.
That being said, it should not appear in models. The model-based-quantifier-instantiation (MBQI) module accidentally "leaks" the `array-ext` into the model. I fixed the problem.

- http://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/185f125f7a3d356192df272bfb2339ad36d3cdf9

The fix is already available in the `unstable` (work-in-progress) branch.
It will also be available in the [nightly builds](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/leonardo/blog/2013/02/15/precompiled.html).

Here is the output after the bug fix:

```
(define-fun pipeid () (Array Int Int)
  (_ as-array k!2))
(define-fun valid () (Array Int Bool)
  (_ as-array k!0))
(define-fun ispipe () (Array Int Bool)
  (_ as-array k!1))
(define-fun pipeid_ab () Int
  2)
(define-fun fd () Int
  0)
(define-fun k!3 ((x!1 Int)) Int
  0)
(define-fun k!0!4 ((x!1 Int)) Bool
  (ite (= x!1 3) false
    true))
(define-fun k!0 ((x!1 Int)) Bool
  (k!0!4 (k!3 x!1)))
(define-fun k!1 ((x!1 Int)) Bool
  true)
(define-fun k!2!5 ((x!1 Int)) Int
  (ite (= x!1 3) 4
    1))
(define-fun k!2 ((x!1 Int)) Int
  (k!2!5 (k!3 x!1)))
pipeid[0] => 1
pipeid[1] => 1
```